# How to get an icon to appear in IOS Safari's Suggested Website list

Tags: ios, safari

I'm trying to figure out how to get my site icon to appear in the iOS Safari Suggested Websites section rather than the default grey Safari icon/placeholder.  Other sites are able to do this, but I can't figure out how.  I assumed it was related to either the `favicon.ico` or `apple-touch-icon.png` file, but I haven't been able to nail down what's being used or how to get it to work for my site.

For example, when I clear my Safari cache and history, open Safari, and start typing "arstechnica", I get this:

[image: arstechnica screengrab]

Same idea when I type in "americanexpress":

[image: american express screen grab]

And "cnn":

[image: cnn screen grab]

But, when I try other sites, such as "wellsfargo", I get the placeholder (which is what's happening for my site as well):

[image: wells fargo screen grab]

My `apple-touch-icon.png` wasn't in the root folder, so I moved it but that didn't seem to make any difference.  (My `favicon.ico` was already in the root folder.)

Upon investigating some of these sites, it doesn't seem to be either the `favicon.ico` or the `apple-touch-icon.png` file that's being used.  arstechnica had an `apple-touch-icon.png` file (through a cdn redirect), but it's not the same image as the one used for the Suggested Sites.  It did have a `favicon.ico` that looked like it matched, but the americanexpress `favicon.ico` wasn't a match to the Suggested Sites icon, either.  Examining each HTML file for `link` tags yielded inconclusive results as well.

Does anybody know what image file is used for the Suggested Sites icon and how I can get it to show up for my website?

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to put a file called --> home_badge_64.png in the root folder of the website.

This would go in your head tag:

```
<link href="/home_badge_64.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
```

As a real life example I'm trying to get to work right now --> http://www.sisltd.ca/home_badge_64.png

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the icon is taken from the OpenGraph `og:image` metatag. I just put it on my website, and changing the value of that tag changed the icon shown in the suggested website item.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="link_to_your_icon.ext" />
```

I had all other OpenGraph tags too, so I didn't test if that metatag alone works or you need all others.